# Increase tap detection area of a widget?

Tags: flutter

I was wondering if it is possible to increase the "tap area" of a specific widget?

A small example would be a 50 by 50 button. If a user taps anywhere on those 50 by 50 pixels the button's `onPressed` would be executed. However can I make it so that if a user clicks lets say 5 pixels above the button, its `onPressed` would still be executed?

I just want to increase this area to provide a better user experience without having to increase the actual size of the button which would make the UI worse.

Comment: If you have space around the button, you can wrap the child widget (of say `RaisedButton`) with `Padding` widget.

Comment: That's a very smart workaround and in some cases of my app this works however it happens a lot that I don't have enough enough space. Also if I wrap the `Raised Button`'s child with a padding wouldn't that increase the size of the button as well? Which is what i want to avoid

Answer (score 38):

I'm a bit late to this, however you kinda got 2 options.

The answers before me are very basic and only use basic containers which wont help you.

1) Use `behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent` on your gestureDetector, this will allow invisible things to be tapped. However you want more than the area you set to be tappable so go to option 2.

2) Use an invisible Stack. Stack a container above your button, make it invisible, add gesture detection on it, with the correct HitTestBehaviour, and this should work fine. If your button is 50x50, make the container 55x55 and stack them on top of eachother, and problem solved.

Comment: Could you please provide an example on how to create the invisible stack you refer to in your answer?

Comment: `behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent` is essential for small text and icon gesture detections. IF you notice that some taps are not being picked up by your gesture detector, enable this for much better performance.

Comment: Great answer and as above small text needs this otherwise you have a small hit area, thanks

Comment: If one adds a 55x55 container to a Stack widget, the whole Stack becomes 55x55, when you want a 50x50 size.
How do we handle this overflow without causing layout issues or rendering issues?

Answer (score 8):

For me I had a very small widget I wanted to keep small for UI however for UX I wanted to have a decent touch area to not frustrate users. For this I found an easy package

https://pub.dev/packages/expand_tap_area/install

Add this to your pubspec.yaml

```
 expand_tap_area: ^1.1.0
```

Import this

```
import 'package:expand_tap_area/expand_tap_area.dart';
```

Simply use the widget. The tapPadding allows you to change the touch area. Other than that works just like Gesture Dector.

```
ExpandTapWidget(
  onTap: () {},
  tapPadding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
  child: smallWidget(),
),
```

Answer (score 7):

You can accomplish this with using `behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent` on `GestureDetector`.

And using `Padding` widget for your child widget, then you can just give extra hit area with padding value.

```
 GestureDetector(
                  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent, // Needed for invisible things to be tapped.
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(9.0), // Configure hit area.
                    child: FaIcon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.xmark,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap your `RaisedButton` into a `Container` and add some padding to the `Container`. 
Then you can wrap the `Container` into a `GestureDetector`, which enables multiple clicks events to a widget.

The `GestureDetector` has also a `onTap` callback which you can use to execute the same code as when the real `RaisedButton` has been clicked.

Here is a simple code example:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Stackoverflow example'),
      ),

      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: Container(
            width: 120,
            height: 80,            

            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),

            color: Colors.blueAccent,

            child: Center(
              child: RaisedButton(                
                child: Text('Click me'),
                onPressed: _fireButtonClick,
              ),
            )         
          ),
          onTap: _fireButtonClick
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now extract your `RaisedButton` `onPressed` code into a dedicated function which you can assign to both the `RaisedButton` `onPressed` and `GestureDetector` `onTap` callbacks:

```
void _fireButtonClick() {
  print('button clicked');
}
```

Hope this helps, Doobie

Comment: I appreciate the effort but this would require extra spacing around the button itself which in my case would not be ideal. This is what i am currently doing now as my button is wrapped with a container and i'm doing something very similar but i was trying to find a more ideal solution that directly increases the "hitbox" of a button

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use TapRegion to implement this. 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TapRegion-class.html

In this following code:

```
  Widget _buildButton(VoidCallback onTap) {
    return Builder(builder: (context) {
      return TapRegion(
        onTapOutside: (event) {
          final renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
          if (renderBox == null) return;
          final tapRegionRect = renderBox.paintBounds
              .inflate(6); // increase the tappable area by 6.

          final tapOutSideLocalOffset = renderBox.globalToLocal(event.position);

          if (tapRegionRect.contains(tapOutSideLocalOffset)) {
            onTap.call();
          }
        },
        onTapInside: (_) {
          onTap.call();
        },
        child: Container(
          width: 30,
          height: 30,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0x26FF6D01),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(23))),
          child: const Text('One'),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you wrap the button in a `Container`, make the `Container` transparent and a `GestureDetection` Widget and then write the code you have in your `onPressed` for the button into the `OnTap` for the `GestureDetector` Widget:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to Ulysses Alves' question about an example of an invisible Stack:

```
Stack(children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 150,
                        height: 40,
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: const Text('Your text here')),
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          ...
                        });
                      }),
                ]),
```

Comment: This works okay for text, or something you want in a large container, but what if you want the child to be _smaller_ than the container, and the wrapping container to not affect layout, like the OP asked?

Answer (score -1):

You can use InkWell's onTap: (){}
and make padding around it's child.

```
InkWell(
onTap: (){
{Function you want to call}
},
child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(
{ any double number})
),
```

Or as an alternative you can look at

```
InkWell( onTap: () {},
child: Ink(width: {desired number}
height: {desired number}
child: child))
```