# How to make the entire area of ​the cell perceive touch?

Tags: flutter

There is a **Table** which contains **TableRow** which contains **GestureDetector**:

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      //
    },
    child: Container(
      width: 110,
      height: 100,
      child: Icon(
        MaterialCommunityIcons.circle_outline,
        size: 50,
      ),
    ),
),
```

It looks like this https://ibb.co/PgVGHy7

But the cell with icon can be tapped closer to the center of the cell. If I tap it closer to the right of the left side then it does not tap. When I make the width of the container bigger it gives nothing.
How to make the entire area of ​​the cell perceive touch?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57114433/increase-tap-detection-area-of-a-widget

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is to add `behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent` to your GestureDetector:

This will make sure that invisible stuff (like empty container space) is tappable, in my case tapping on a title box that had a very short title.

```
GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
...)
```

From source code:

```
/// How to behave during hit tests.
enum HitTestBehavior {
  /// Targets that defer to their children receive events within their bounds
  /// only if one of their children is hit by the hit test.
  deferToChild,

  /// Opaque targets can be hit by hit tests, causing them to both receive
  /// events within their bounds and prevent targets visually behind them from
  /// also receiving events.
  opaque,

  /// Translucent targets both receive events within their bounds and permit
  /// targets visually behind them to also receive events.
  translucent,
}
```

Comment: hrrm, can you try adding the CELL as a CHILD of the gesture detector? and then everything else like the icon inside the CELLs child. This should then make the entire cell tappable even if it has a 1x1px dot in it. From flutter docs: "By default a GestureDetector with an invisible child ignores touches; this behavior can be controlled with behavior."