# Increase tap area for gesture detector

Tags: flutter

I need to increase the tap area for gesture detector. I tried wrapping it in a stack and added gesture detector to the top widget which is basically an empty container

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        _button(),
        GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
          child: Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 80,
            color: Colors.redAccent.withOpacity(0.5), // remove this
          ),
          onTap: () {
            print('tapped');
          },
          onPanUpdate: (details) => ....,
          onPanEnd: (details) => ....,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DbFI.jpg)

As you can see in the screenshot I have a text which can be scaled in height. In order to do so I have added a button:

```
  Widget _button() {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.grey[500],
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: widget.size / 4,
          width: widget.size,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

But I need to increase the tap area and so the stack solution. But it's not working unless I tap in the center(right on top of the _button()). Why is that happening even when I wrapped the empty container with gesture detector?

The top button in the screenshot attached is positioned on the dash lines:

```
    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      fit: StackFit.passthrough,
      children: <Widget>[
        child,
        Positioned(
          top: -25,
          right: widget.item!.width / 2,
          child: TopScaleButton(
            widget.item!,
            size: buttonSize,
            canvasKey: canvasKey,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, in a stack, the widget are stacked on to of each other, so you might need to switch the order of your two widgets in the stack.

Comment: The order is correct. The button widget is smaller so it's on the bottom. And the empty container is expanding the tap area so it goes on top which is then wrapped with the gesture detector. got the reference from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57114433/increase-tap-detection-area-of-a-widget