# Flutter: Increase tap area of button (InkResponse)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have an SVG icon and I struggle to make the **tap area** of it bigger, without making the icon bigger itself.

The icon is pretty small and so the tap area is small as well. But for UI reasons I do not want to make the icon bigger, is there any solution to increasing the tap area for this?

Here is my code snippet:

```
Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 55),
        child: InkResponse(
          onTap: () {},
          child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/svg/regular/bell.svg",
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight, height: 24.w, width: 24.w),
        ),
      )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase tap detection area of a widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57114433/increase-tap-detection-area-of-a-widget)

Answer (score 0):

you can just wrap the `SvgPicture` with another widget that can expand padding or size.
A better approach is the `Padding` widget :

```
  Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 55.w),
    child: InkResponse(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/svg/regular/bell.svg",
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight, height: 24.w, width: 24.w),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

or with `sizedBox` :

Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 55.w),
child: InkResponse(
onTap: () {},
child: SizedBox(
width: 100,
height: 100,
child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/svg/regular/bell.svg",
alignment: Alignment.centerRight, height: 24.w, width: 24.w),
),
),
),